# How to emit particles according to object movement?

Tags: particles, weight-painting

I'm animating an underwater robot. I'd like him to emit particles (bubbles) as soon as he moves (X and Y direction). 
Is there a possibility to convert the coordinate-changerate to particle emission? Or a ideas for a work-around?

I already tried the Vertex Weight Proximity Modifier, but the particle emission work only staticly with it. The screenshots show an example of the weight paint according to the distance to the empty. In the beginning, the particles fit the weight paint. But as the empty moves on to the other side, the particles just ignore the change of weight paint.
What do to?

[image]
[image]

Best reguards,
OldPowel

Comment: Maybe using a vertex weights proximity modifier and make so the vertex group weights influences the particle emission?

Comment: Good idea, edited my post.

Comment: FYI http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/is-it-possible-to-change-the-emission-rate-of-particles-over-time... so this is not the good approach... for now!

Comment: As the vertex weights is not a solution, you should have a look at this with some possibilities given by Animation Nodes http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67207/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-brownian-motion-to-a-specific-axis/74860#74860. Here you can control all the bubbles in time